# Remove DTC Support From SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, msdtc

My application is running in Azure SQL which doesn't support DTC. We only use Azure SQL in upper environments. In the local development environments, we're still using SQL Server 2016.

I want to avoid a situation, which has happened a couple of times in past where a developer has ended up writing queries with a transaction that ended up escalating to DTC, which of course was only caught in upper environments.

I'm looking for a command to run in SQL Server to completely remove its ability to participate in DTC, basically make it like its Azure SQL counterpart.

Edit: I don't want to remove MSDTC from the system itself as I've other services, that doesn't involve Database, that requires MSDTC.

Comment: Have you tried disabling the Distributed Transaction Coordinator service via the [services.msc MMC snap-in](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsvistanow/2009/03/30/running-microsoft-management-console-mmc-snap-ins-from-the-start-menu/)?

Comment: Keep in mind that Azure SQL is a different product with a different engine that is on a 100% different release cycle than SQL Server - you're bound to encounter more issues like this as time goes on.

Comment: are these linked server queries? if so, you could try setting "remote proc transaction promotion" on the linked server definition to false